# Erreur gdal_polygonize.py package ARfun with R

Tags: python, raster, r, polygon-creation, rgdal

I'm a french student, in advance I'm sorry for my english. I'm installed the package `APfun` on R to transform Raster to Polygons with `Appolygonize` function. But I have a error :

```
crownsPoly <- raster(paste(getwd(), "/Output_data/crownpoly.tif", sep = ""))

   APpolygonize(crownsPoly, 
+              readToMemory = TRUE, 
+              outFile = paste(getwd(), "/Output_data/segmentation.shp", sep = ""),
+              OSGeoPath = "C:\\OSGeo4W64", 
+              connectivity = 4)

Error in APpolygonize(corwnsPoly, readToMemory = TRUE, outFile = paste(getwd(),  : 
  Could not find required file 'C:\OSGeo4W64/bin\gdal_polygonize.py'
```

This function need to OSGeo4W (for GDAl), I have realised this installation with https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ like hep package advised.

I find `gdal_polygonize.py` within the folder `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\Scripts`. But the function research this file within `C:\OSGeo4W64/bin\gdal_polygonize.py`so it is nowhere to be found.

Why OSGeo4W installation put this file within bad localisation ? When I put this file in the good folder (where the function search) it's a other file which is absent...

I realised a new installation of OSGeo4W6 and this error was yet present...

When I search `gdal_polygonize.py` in r, I have nothing :

```
> Sys.which("gdal_polygonize.py")
gdal_polygonize.py 
                ""
```

Do it have other manipulation between OSGeo4W64 and the launch of the function `APpolygonize` ?

I use Windows, Rstudio with "R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)" and I have Python 3.7.3 in my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `st_as_sf` method for `stars` objects.

Here's an example using a DEM tif included with `stars`:

```r
library(stars)
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)

f <- system.file(package='stars', 'tif/olinda_dem_utm25s.tif')
r <- stars::read_stars(f) > 40
r[r==0] <- NA # here I don't want polygons for class 0, so setting it to NA
poly <- sf::st_as_sf(r, merge=TRUE)
poly <- lwgeom::st_make_valid(poly) # as per ?stars:::st_as_sf.stars
sf::write_sf(poly, 'poly.gpkg')
```

```
plot(poly)
```

[image]

If you need it as an `sp` object, you can coerce it with `sf::as_Spatial(poly)`.

Comment: I successful ! Thanks you for your help ! But I don't understand where is my error in my first code. This method is as fast as my first code ? Because my raster to convert is big ...

Comment: @Romain - As you say, the function looks for gdal_polygonize.py at c:/ OSGeo4W64/bin. You could try copying the .py file to that path, or else modify the function source. I’m not sure about relative performance of my solution above vs what you’re attempting - haven’t benchmarked it.